# Lost data after store and reload of UIImage in iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimage

I have developed an iOS7 app. I use the UIImagePickerController to get a UIImage. During the usage of the app an image
is stored to the local app directory and loaded. The file will be overwritten several times. I use UIImagePNGRepresentation and NSData storeToFile to store
the picture. In order to load the image I use UIImage initWithContentsOfFile.
It works fine for some store and load processes. With the Debugger I can confirm that the picture is stored and loaded appropriately.
But after some time the stored picture does not contain a picture anymore. When I look at the load procedure with the debugger I can see that
a picture is loaded but it seems to be completely transparent with no other information.
This phenomenon only occurs on a device and not during a simulation with the simulator. Furthermore, the effect seems to occur only when the app is kicked out of the memory (double tap of the home button)

I debugged the app for hours but I cannot imagine the reasons for this behaviour. Additionally it is difficult to debug due to the complete termination of the app. Does anybody know a solution or has been faced with the same problem? Could anybody give me a hint what to debug to track down the problem?

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated. :)

Thanks for your answers. Here is a code excerpt:

Code to store image:
Generate file path in documents directory

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ImageforButton%i.png",i];
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *file = [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
```

Create NSData from UIImage (image is a UIImage that always has the correct image data)

```
NSData *picData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Write NSData to file

```
[picData writeToFile:file atomically:true];
```

Code to load image:
Generate file path

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ImageforButton%i.png",i];
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *file = [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
```

Load picture
UIImage *img;

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file isDirectory:false] == true)
{
img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self saveFilePath:name]];
}
```

img does not always contain the right data. Before the app is completely terminated img
contains the expected picture. After the app was completely terminated a valid
UIImage can be loaded to img but it seems only to contain a transparent picture.
All in all it does not contain the right picture anymore.

Comment: Hey there, you're going to want to add some code, tell us which variable you expect to hold what, and what is the actual result instead. Going to be hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Are you storing the image to the cache directory? If you are, it can be cleared at any time without notice by the system. If you want it to be always there, you need to store it in the Documents directory